# Android: fragments in Activity: after popBackStack() the number of present fragments stills the same

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my Activity, I add the first Fragment (myFragmentA) in onCreate() method:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(enterAnim, exitAnim, popEnterAnim, popExitAnim)
                .add(containerViewId, myFragmentA, fragmentTag)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
```

In this first fragment, when I click on a Button, I add a new fragment (myFragmentB):

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(enterAnim, exitAnim, popEnterAnim, popExitAnim)
                .replace(containerViewId, myFragmentB, fragmentTag)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
```

All is great to this point.

When I catch back pressed from Activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // >>> Just to prevent to keep the first fragment !!
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().size() > 1) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}
```

Back pressed from myFragmentB > myFragmentA : OK

Back pressed from myFragmentA (just to verify there is no popback) : FAILED. myFragmentA is removed too! And I want to keep it always. I don't know why getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().size() is equal 2!

Thanks for your helps guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i correctly understood.

You want to use

```
getBackStackEntryCount()
```

instead of

```
getFragments().size()
```

Take a look at the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You see, your container activity gets added to the back stack by default. In your code you have written addToBackStack(null) for both the fragments, this will add your fragments to the back stack over and above your activity which gets added to the back stack by default. This explains why you are seeing size 2, one may be your activity and the other your fragment.